# Value of type 'ListViewController.Pokemon' has no subscripts

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I want to return Pokemon names from PokeApi, but I have this error :
**Value of type 'ListViewController.Pokemon' has no subscripts**.

Here's my code :

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemon1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemon2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemon3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemon4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemon5: UILabel!
    
    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData(from: url)
    }
    
    
    
    func fetchData(from url: String) {
        let url = URL(string: url)
        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if(error != nil) {
                print(String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            
            var json: Pokemon
            
            do {
                json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokemon.self, from: data!)
                Swift.print(json)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self.pokemon1.text = json[0].name
                    self.pokemon2.text = json[1].results.name
//                    self.pokemon3.text = json[0].results.name
//                    self.pokemon4.text = json[3].name
//                    self.pokemon5.text = json[4].name
                    //callback: fonction que j'appelle à la suite d'un évènement
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume() // Commence la dataTask si elle n'est pas en marche actuellement
    }
    
    struct Pokemon: Codable {
        let results: [Result]
    }
    
    struct Result: Codable {
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }
}
```

I checked with the print and I am receiving the json data. here's what's in the print :

```
Pokemon(results: [RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "bulbasaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "ivysaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "venusaur", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "charmander", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "charmeleon", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "charizard", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "squirtle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "wartortle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "blastoise", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "caterpie", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "metapod", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "butterfree", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "weedle", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "kakuna", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "beedrill", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "pidgey", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "pidgeotto", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "pidgeot", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "rattata", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"), RattrapageIOS.ListViewController.Result(name: "raticate", url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/")])
```

What seems to be the issue ?

Comment: I also tried this : `self.pokemon4.text = json[3].name` and it didn't work neither, showing up the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the `Pokemon` type and get it's name, but `name` is  a property of the `Result` type, instances of which are in the results array.  What you want is:

```
json.results[0].name
```

to get the name of the first item in the array.   If you used more informative names for your types the issue would have been more obvious.  eg.

```
struct Wrapper: Codable {
        let results: [Pokemon]
    }
    
    struct Pokemon: Codable {
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }
}
```

and then you'd need

```
let wrapped = try JSONDecoder().decode(Wrapper.self, from: data!)
let pokemons = wrapped.results

//etc

self.pokemon2.text = pokemons[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks ! It even works without the wrapper